# Finding Linear Transformation Matrix $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

a) Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear transformation such that $T(1,1) = (1,2)$ and $T(1,2)=(3,4)$. Find $T(5,8)$ and $T(3,-2)$ ?

b) Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear transformation such that $T(1,0,-1) = (2,3)$ and $T(2,1,3) = (-1,0)$. Find $T(8,3,7)$?

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: This is not a place for dumping unmotivated, context-free questions with no sign of individual thought. What do you know about linear transformations, Jack? Can you think of a useful way to relate $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ to $(5,8)$? Please put some effort in, or at least let us know what the difficulty is.

Comment: See the previous posted links "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280791/suppose-t-is-a-linear-transformation-such-that-t1-1-1-0-1-2-t1-0-1-1", "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454523/finding-an-unknown-linear-transformation-given-that-t1-1-1-0-2-and-t2-3"

Comment: @Jack For the second $T$, one more equation is needed.

Comment: @Ajay, not if the third triple is a linear combination of the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Solve $a(1,1)+b(1,2)=(5,8)$ for $a$ and $b$.  You should get $a=2, b=3$.

Now "use linearity".  By that I mean $T(5,8)=2T(1,1)+3T(1,2)$.

The other problem is similar.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let the matrix be $$T = \begin{bmatrix} x & z \\ y & w \end{bmatrix} $$

Given $$ T \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\  1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\  2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} x \\  y\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} z \\  w\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\  2\end{bmatrix}$$ $$ \Rightarrow x + z = 1, y + w = 2$$ Similarly for second example, $$ x + 2z = 3, y + 2w = 4$$
Which on solving gives, $$T  = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $$

2. You can't do that analytically. Since there are $3$ unknowns and $2$ equations.

Comment: But you don't need to find $T$ in order to find $T(8,3,7)$.

Comment: that was a trick then , I guess.

Comment: Expressing a given vector as a linear combination of two other given vectors, and then using the linearity property of linear transformations, I'm not sure I'd call that a trick.